# Amazon EC2 Container Service(ECS)をつかってインスタンス間の接続がしたい

Tags: aws, docker

Amazon EC2 Container Service(ECS)をつかって

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/images/application.png

のような構成をつくりたいと思っています

nginx + php-fpm + mysql
だとすると、それぞれのタスク定義を

- nginxタスク
- php-fpmタスク
- mysqlタスク

と別々につくり

serviceを
- front service には nginxタスク
- backend service には php-fpmタスク
- data service には mysqlタスク

を紐付ければいいとは思うのですが、
ここから、php-fpmからmysqlへのつなぎ方が分かりません
どうやって紐付けられるでしょうか？

タスク定義内のlinkの指定だと、同じタスク定義内のcontainerしか紐付けられなさそうでした